# jquery datatables add new row alphabetically

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am currently using jQuery datatables in one of my project. What I am stuck with is to be able to add a new row dynamically and at the same time add the row in alphabetical order position.

I understand that I need to use fnadddata from the API to add a row but this function only add the new row to the end of the table. It does not add according to alphabetical order. Hence I cook up my own code to find the position to add the row manually.

```
$(".rowList").each(function( ) {
    if( $(this).text( ).toLowerCase( ) > eObj.response.name.toLowerCase( ) ) {
        $(this).closest("tr").before( eObj.response.html ); // html is the new row from server
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code above find the alphabetical position and creates a new row in the table accordingly. But of course, as I'm not using datatables fnaddData function, once the row is added and when I click on some event on the table (For e.g: sorting, searching, filtering), the new row disappeared.

I understand this because of the DOM and cache issue of datatables. So is there a way for me to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just insert it at the end using fnadddata and then sort the rows based on the column's alphabetical value?

Comment: Thanks for your reply weexthis. I tried to do that but the sorting of the new row in datatables either just goes to the top, or to the bottom. It can't sort according to alphabetical

Answer (score 0):

fnAddData most certainly does sort the table after it has run - example: http://live.datatables.net/aceyed/edit#javascript,html . Please link to a test case showing the issue.

Comment: fnAddData documentation also shows that it sorts by default, but you can also turn off the sorting if you want: https://datatables.net/api